# Slickgrid tree view

Tags: slickgrid

I am new to UI development. I am working on a project which already uses slickgrid for displaying reports. My project uses SlickGrid v1.4. I want modify the current reports and implement tree view in the reports. I am passing the parent for each element from backend to UI.

Questions:

1. Do I need to upgrade slickgrid to its latest version. If yes then is it backward compatible?
2. How can I implement this parent child relationship in slickgrid, like what properties that I will be using?

Let me know if you need more details on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the javascript slickgrid, then you need to specifically look at this example of slickgrid
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example5-collapsing.html

This is an implementation rather than a feature so any version should be fine. So yes better go with latest if possible.

Its just an implementation of tree view using indents. Its different from other libraries where they have specific views for tree structure.

What you should do on the backend is, send an array with list of items to the frontend. the data item should have 2 attributes parent and level.
The parent will be null for root and level 0. if an item is child of some parent. The level of child will be 1 and parent 0 (index of array). (as implemented in slickgrid)
Please note parent value can be anything based on your data. For example a hierarchy of categories.

```
var item1 = {id: "id_1", category:"cat1" parent: null, }
var item2 = {id: "id_2", parent: "cat1"};
```

So the level attribute shows the depth of current item in the hierarchy.

The slick grid in the example uses the level value to put indents or spaces.

You can either use the same logic or may be apply specific css3 classes based on the level and customize according to your needs.

```
.class[level=0] {}
```

So slick grid is flexible that way. You just need the data in a particular format.

One important thing is the array of items should already be sorted by the field and level for this to work.

Some databases like Oracle already provide you options like *connect by prior* to get data in this format. there is a reserved keyword level which can be added as a column name.
Also this is assuming that you table is already designed in a way to represent hierarchal structure.

```
SELECT category_id, cat_name, cat_parent_id, LEVEL
FROM categories
CONNECT BY PRIOR category_id = cat_parent_id;
```

You can also fetch data from a specified root

```
START WITH category_id = 5
```